# How to get object boolean type in an if statement

Tags: android, if-statement

I have a constructor class object here:

```
public class Question {



   public  String question;
   public   boolean correctAnswer;


    public Question(String question, boolean correctAnswer)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }
```

}

In my MainActivity I am creating questions and storing them in a List.

Then i want to make an f/else statement on button click so that when a user clicks button and the questions boolean type matches the if statement it is prompted to another question. The problem is I dont know how to get the questions boolean type.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button mYes;
    Button mNo;
    TextView mQuestion;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final int[] count = {0};
        mYes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mNo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //Creating question
        final Question first = new Question("Do i understand this code?", false);
        final Question second = new Question("kas tas?", true);
        //question list
        final ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        //adding question
        questions.add(first);
        questions.add(second);
        //show the question.
        mQuestion.setText(questions.get(0).question);

        mYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                    if () {
                        count[0]++;
                        mQuestion.setText(questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size()).question);
                    } else {

                        finish();

                    }

            }

        });
```

I can get one Questions boolean type by writing first.correctAnswer. However I need all of the questions. Should I count all the questions with a for statement? If so how do I extrect the boolean type from that?

Comment: I agree to the first question-answer written in your code :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a boolean arrayList to keep answers i.e. true, false, true, true ...

```
ArrayList<boolean> answers = new ArrayList<boolean>();
```

As you are already keeping the count of the question,
You should match the answer from the list onClick event...

```
if (answers.get(count[0])) { // if answer == true
   count[0]++; // increase count
   /// do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped. Thank you. I have one more simple question for the future. Currently I am adding questions like this: questions.add(first). Lets say in the future I will have 100questions. Do I need to add all of them like this? Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: a better way would be questions.add(new Question("Do i understand this code?", false));    Every time you write a new question, write in add method...